# Cadastro de Banco de dados

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

Meu banco de dados possui esta estrutura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para criar o registro em **PESSOAS** e ao mesmo tempo obter o ID e salva-lo em **PESSOAS_FISICAS**.

Eu criei este comando para tal, mais não funcionou.

```
select ID_PESSOAS,
   NOME,
   CPF,
   SEXO,
   ENDERECO,
   COMPLEMENTO,
   CIDADE,
   ESTADO,
   FK_ID_PESSOAS
from DB_PESSOAS, DB_PESSOAS_FISICAS
WHERE (DB_PESSOAS.ID_PESSOAS = DB_PESSOAS_FISICAS.FK_ID_PESSOAS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá amigo tudo bem? bom acho que o que você está procurando é o lastInsertId. Ele é responsável por pegar o último Id cadastrado no banco, então dessa forma você pode cadastrar o ID (Tabela PESSOAS ) em (PESSOAS_FISICAS).  Como você não disse a linguagem para exemplificar, dê uma pesquisada na sintaxe correta por aí. Bom espero ter ajudado!

Comment: A sintaxe está na tag é [tag:oracle].

Comment: Será que eu consigo fazer isso na mesma tela de inserção? Ou existe algum outro procedimento para preenchimento?

Comment: Sim você consegue fazer na mesma tela de inserção, é cadastrar pegar o último ID antes de fechar a conexão e realizar outro cadastro, com a última ID cadastrada.

Comment: Eu ainda não consegui pois ainda não sei como aplicar isso no APEX, mais fiz alguns testes, e acredito que sirva, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Ao inserir, você precisa obter o valor que foi inserido no campo chave, no seu caso o campo `id`. Após o `insert` use `RETURNING {campo_chave} INTO {variavel}` sabendo que a `variavel` deve ser previamente declarada. Veja o `insert` abaixo:

```
    insert into db_pessoa values (1,'PEDRO') RETURNING id INTO variavel_id;
```

**Abaixo tem um exemplo testado no SQL Fiddle.**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47b9c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE db_pessoa
 (id number
 ,nome CHAR(50)
);

 
 CREATE TABLE db_pessoa_fisica
 (fk_id number
 ,sexo CHAR(50)
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE
   variavel_id number;
BEGIN
   insert into db_pessoa values (1,'PEDRO') RETURNING id INTO variavel_id;
   insert into db_pessoa_fisica values (variavel_id,'MASCULINO');
END;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47b9c/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
select * from db_pessoa
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47b9c/1/1)**:

| ID | NOME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PEDRO |

**Query 3**:

```
select * from db_pessoa_fisica
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47b9c/1/2)**:

| FK_ID | SEXO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MASCULINO |